# how to check the database name that ActiveRecord uses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

In database.yml you define all the settings. How can I access those settings from ruby? I've looked in `App::Application::config`, but can't find it there. Also, I remember people were able to configure database settings without yaml, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```rb
Rails.configuration.database_configuration
```

This will give you a hash table with the configurations for each of your environments. E.g. to get your development database name:

```rb
Rails.configuration.database_configuration["development"]["database"]
```

Comment: To get the current database configuration: `Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]`

Comment: When I try input your command I get this error: "Rails.configuration.database_configuration[development][database]: command not found" - any idea why?

Comment: If somebody adds the following anywhere in your code base, database_configuration will not give you the database being used: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("USE bleh")`


This will: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database`

Comment: This answer was deprecated since Rails 6.1. I explain through the new way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66749039/1974306)

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @williamlopes I can't find any documentation that says `Rails.configuration.database_configuration` is deprecated, although I could easily have missed it.

Comment: It's still working in Rails 7.0.4.3, fwiw.

But the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66749039/295028) from @williamlopes
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config`
gives more concise information.

Comment: @VoA I believe you have to go into Rails console with `bin/rails console`

Answer (score 99):

In Rails 4.2, you can do this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

You can also ask specific models for their database (since it's possible to use different databases per model):

```
User.connection.current_database
```

Comment: This is also a better answer as a simple `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("USE bleh")` would make reading from the database config pointless.

Comment: `User.connection.config` also seems to work in my case, and prints a bunch of other useful info.

Comment: You can also do `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` in Rails 3.2

Answer (score 17):

Since Rails 6.1 you must use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config`. So you can access the others class methods, like `database()`.

```
db_config = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config
print db_config.database
# main available methods: [:host, :schema_cache_path, :migrations_paths, :config, :database, :_database=, :checkout_timeout, :reaping_frequency, :idle_timeout, :replica?, :configuration_hash, :adapter, :pool]
```

Answer (score 11):

An additional way to get more iformation is to use the database specific connection info methods.  For example, if you are using postgresql, you can get details for the current database connection with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.conninfo_hash
```

This will give more connection details, not only those that differ from defaults.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the database name for use within a bash or shell script then use the following:

```sh
db_name="$(bundle exec rails runner "puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database")"
```

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on the comments from tsherif, you can run the Rails.configuration commands inside the rails console (rails c) to get the database names.

Comment: Then to actually run the reset you use heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL, then follow the prompt.